# how to use power supply to power GPU only?

Tags: power-supply, gpu

I have cooler master m2 silent pro. I need to use it because it has necessary pci e cables.
I power motherboard using another power supply. I connected GPU to cooler master properly using 3 pci-e cables. Other psu slots are empty. only GPU is connected to this cooler master PS. GPU doesn't work. The fan of cooler master PS doesn't spin.
But test advised [here](https://landing.coolermaster.com/faq/how-to-test-a-power-supply/) forces fan of PS to spin. Maybe this PS doesn't work if motherboard is not connected...
What to do to power GPU using this cooler master power supply?

Comment: Why are you using a separate power supply?

Comment: Because another power supply has only two pci-e cables and I need 3. Cooler master has necessary 3 cables

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question… why are you using two power supplies rather than just swapping in the correct one?

Comment: Because I need 2 power supply to power the whole system. Neither one can power 2 gpu with 300 w each. I just need to force cooler master to work with gpu only

Comment: This may not be the answer you want to hear, but the solution is to buy a power supply capable of producing enough power to run all your components, then sell the insufficient one.

Comment: Thanks, this excellent idea didn't come to my mind. but I expect answer on my question.

Comment: So when you short the pins and the fan spins it still does not power the gpu?

Comment: @Moab I didn't try. I know that this article suggest how to test power supply. And test is passed good. But I don't know whether it's safe to plug gpu in such test mode

Comment: All the pin short does is turn on the PSU, I have powered many devices using this method and never had an issue.

Comment: @Moab Thank you. If I understood correctly you suggest to short green and any black pin as advised in article I gave link to and connect gpu to PCI-e simultaneously? If yes then you can give an answer. But bear in mind - the card costs 2K :)

Comment: very strange decision to close this question. SuperUser is exactly for such questions. Voluntarism of moderators is killing this forum. I don't need answer because I found answer myself. But if moderators close such questions this reduces chances to find ready answer next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution: I used technique mentioned in link given in my question: short of green and black line turns on power supply. Simultaneously I plugged PCI-e device to power supply. It works for 2 days without any issues.